# Best approach for store user session in reactjs application

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a reactjs appliacation with a service oriented architecture in which data will accessed through web services. There is also a login feature in it. I am confused about where I store the user session after login i.e. `localStorage or cookies`. Which one is the best. 
There are some pros and crons of both of that. Like,

- local storage can be accessed using javascript and also all browser
  does not support local storage whereas
- cookies have too low web storage to store data as compare to local
  storage and also with each server calls cookies will send the data
  stored to server, this will affect the site’s performance.

So I just need your help to find the better way to do this. 
Sorry for the english if something wrong. Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Theres not *that solution*. You've got all arguments already, decide wisely ;)

Comment: @Jonas, thanks for the quick response. What's your suggestion ?